# Blueprint, Spring DM and DS

Tags: blueprint-osgi, spring-dm

I am a little bit confused about Blueprint, Spring DM and DS (Declarative Services).

Form what I think it is:

1. Spring DM came first.
2. OSGi like the idea and defined the Blueprint standard based on Spring DM.
3. Spring DM became the reference implementation of Blueprint.

No?

And how does DS (Declarative Services) fit into the picture?

Answer (score 0):

Well some others did not like the idea and created declarative services :-)

Blueprint is largely xml focused and declarative services is largely annotation focused. In the end I think it would have been better to have one project that allows both.